# SAS length warning : Multiple lengths were specified for the variable np by input data set(s)

Tags: sas

I want to set two datasets with different length of the same variable. My example:
data set 1
det np ord
C    5   0
data set 2
det np     ord
A    1(10)   1
B    3(30)   2

Could someone help me in order to set these 2 datasets correctly without warning?

Many thanks!!

I want to set these 2 datasets correctly without warning. My final dataset will be

det  np     ord
C    5       0
A    1(10)   1
B    3(30)   2

Comment: data set 1                                                                                                                                             det np ord                                                                                                                                           C     5    0

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the following situation with two data sets with different lengths in column "det":

```
data have1;
  length det $4 np ord c $10;
  det='1234';np='np1'; ord='ord1';
  c='c text';
run;

data have2;
  length det $5 np ord a b $10;
  det='12345'; np='np2'; ord='ord2';
  a='a sample';
  b='b others';
run;
```

If you put them together by a simple data step there will be a warning due to different lengths depending on the order of your input data sets:

```
data want1;
  set have1 have2;
run;

WARNING: Multiple lengths were specified for the variable det by input data set(s). This can cause truncation of data.
```

And here is the code without warning:

```
data want2;
  set have2 have1;
run;

/* Sort step, just to get the original order */
proc sort data=want2;
  by det;
quit;
```

Keep in mind that in the first case the warning will have real consequences because your data is eventually truncated because the resulting column *det* will have a length of 4. So, in the example above the second row will have *det*="1234" instead of "12345", i.e. want1 looks like that:

```
det     np  ord     c      a        b 
-------------------------------------------------   
1234    np1 ord1    c text      
1234    np2 ord2           a sample b others
```

In the case of want2 the length will be 5 and there will not be any truncation.

Explanation: Concerning the length of a column in a resulting data set SAS takes the length of the first occurrence of a variable.

But the best way to avoid this warning is to define the lengths for the resulting table *before* the set statement. In this way you can also define the order of the resulting columns:

```
data want;
  length det $5 np ord c a b $10;
  set have1 have2;
run;
```